# Which devices support iOS 7's burst mode?

Tags: photos, ios

The new burst mode in iOS 7 was demoed at the iPhone event, but I couldn't tell whether that's just a feature of the iPhone 5S or whether that was an iOS 7 feature. Which devices support it?

Comment: Not an official answer - but my 4S does have burst mode...

Comment: I have used burst mode on iPhone 5 and iPad 3, both take multiple pictures but not at the speed mentioned for the 5S. They don't however show the best picture and allow you to choose which photos to add to the camera roll, all photos just end up in the camera role.

Answer (score 4):

According to [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2013/09/17/ios-7-review-apple/):

> All phones capable of installing iOS 7 get a variant of burst mode, in fact, which takes pictures in rapid succession, but not at the 10fps rate of the iPhone 5s, and without the auto selection feature that suggests which shot is best.

And [CNET](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57602511-285/five-tips-for-the-new-camera-app-on-ios-7/):

> What Apple didn't mention is that older iOS devices would also be gaining the ability to take photos in succession, just not nearly as fast or with the same software powering the editing process.

[TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/09/19/ios-7-camera-changes-make-it-better-but-it-still-loves-to-cras/):

> You can use burst mode on older models of the iPhone, and it works pretty well, but you don't get the speed nor the auto-selection mode that burst mode on the iPhone 5s has.

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's website, only the 5s supports burst mode. From left to right (5s, 5c, 4s).

[image]

Source: http://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/

Comment: How do you explain the two comments then? Those users say that burst mode works on the 4S, 5, and the iPad 3…

Comment: @daviesgeek I cannot, but I'm assuming Apple did not have made a mistake on their website. Likely that those commenting think they are running burst mode but it's actually not (bug in iOS 7).

Comment: "All phones capable of installing iOS 7 get a variant of burst mode, in fact, which takes pictures in rapid succession, but not at the 10fps rate of the iPhone 5s, and without the auto selection feature that suggests which shot is best." ~ [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2013/09/17/ios-7-review-apple/)

Comment: @daviesgeek There you go. So their website is accurate. Only the 5s gets "true" burst mode.